# Displaying garbage value

Tags: c++14, c++17

When the friendly function add is used to print the value of `sum` variable of two classes, the correct output is printing. But, when then display function of their respective class are used, garbage value is printing. 
What's wrong with the code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DB;

class DM {
    int m, cm;
    float sum;

public:
    void read()
    {
        cout << "Enter meters and centimeters respectively\n";
        cin >> m >> cm;
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << sum << " meters\n";
    }
    friend void add(DM p1, DB p2);
};

class DB {
    int feet, inch;
    float sum;

public:
    void read()
    {
        cout << "Enter feets and inches respectively\n";
        cin >> feet >> inch;
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << sum << " feets\n";
    }
    friend void add(DM p1, DB p2);
};

void add(DM p1, DB p2)
{
    float a = p2.feet * 12;
    float b = a + p2.inch;
    float c = b * .3048 + p1.m + p1.cm * .01;
    //cout << c << endl;
    p1.sum = c;
    //cout << p1.sum << endl;
    //p2.sum = (c/12)/.3048;
    cout << p2.sum << endl;
}

int main()
{
    DM obj1;
    DB obj2;
    obj1.read();
    obj2.read();
    add(obj1, obj2);
    obj1.display();
    obj2.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you print `sum` but you never initialize the `sum` of `obj1` and `obj2`.

You initialize `sum` only inside `add()` but you pass values to `add()` **by** **copy**, so you initialize `sum` only in temporary objects.

When you print `obj1.sum` and `obj2.sum` (through `display()`), the `sum` member are still not-initialized.

So the garbage.

Try passing objects by reference

```
// ..........V........V
void add (DM & p1, DB & p2)
```

This way the initialization of `sum` inside `add()` has effect also for calling objects.